# How can I set up a new column in python with a value based on the return of a function?

Tags: python-3.x

I am doing some text mining in python and want to set up a new column with the value 1 if the return of my search function is true and 0 if it's false.

I have tried various if statements, but cannot get anything to work.

A simplified version of what I'm doing is below:

```
import pandas as pd
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')

df = pd.DataFrame (
        {
        'student number' : [1,2,3,4,5],
        'answer' : [ 'Yes, she is correct.', 'Yes', 'no', 'north east', 'No its North East']
        # I know there's an apostrophe missing
        }
)       
print(df)

# change all text to lower case
df['answer'] = df['answer'].str.lower()

# split the answer into individual words
df['text'] = df['answer'].apply(nltk.word_tokenize)

# Check if given words appear together in a list of sentence 
def check(sentence, words): 
   res = [] 
   for substring in sentence: 
       k = [ w for w in words if w in substring ] 
       if (len(k) == len(words) ): 
            res.append(substring) 
   return res

# Driver code 
sentence = df['text'] 
words = ['no','north','east'] 
print(check(sentence, words))
```

Comment: you mean if answer  contains ['no','north','east'] then is is false answer??

Comment: No, if it includes those words it will be correct, so I want to set up a 'mark' column with a 1 in it if it includes those words and a 0 otherwise. It sounds so simple when I put it like that, but I'm really struggling with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want I think:

```
df['New'] = df['answer'].isin(words)*1
```

This one works for me:

```
for i in range(0, len(df)):
    if set(words) <= set(df.text[i]):
        df['NEW'][i] = 1
    else:
        df['NEW'][i] = 0
```

You don't need the function if you use this method.

Comment: Thank you so much for this, it sets up a new column and enters 1s and 0s, which is what I was struggling to do. This marks the answer that only includes 'no' as correct and all of the others as wrong, when actually only the final answer is correct, so I still need to change it a bit, but it may be because of a fault with my original function.

Comment: @JoPalmer Great!